# QGIS expression for features of two different layers intersecting to a certain percentage

Tags: qgis, intersection, expression, qgis-expression

I am looking for a QGIS expression in Field Calculator that delivers the values "good", "medium" and "bad", depending on the percentage that the geometry of features in Layer 1 (red polygons) intersect with the geometry of feature-class A (green polygon) or feature-class B (yellow polygon) of Layer 2.

If the geometry of Layer 1 features intersects more than 50% with feature-class A geometry of Layer 2, it should be "good", if more then 50% with feature class B geometry of Layer 2 it should be "medium", else "bad".

[image]

I tried the following expression but it delivered "bad" for all features":

```
CASE 
WHEN area(intersection(geometry(get_feature('layer 2', 'feature-class', '1')),$geometry)) / $area > 0.5 
THEN  'good' 
WHEN area(intersection(geometry(get_feature('layer 2', 'feature-class', '2')),$geometry)) / $area > 0.5 
THEN  'medium'  
ELSE 'bad' 
END
```

Do you know what the right expression would be?

Answer (score 4):

Solution below works only for QGIS 3.28 and later.

---

[`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_intersects#overlay-intersects) is the expression you want to use.

It allows you to filter for values of the intersecting layer, e.g. your feature classes. Furthermore, there's the option to set a minimum overlap for the expression to return `true` for the intersection.

I used the following expression to label the smaller polygons in the screenshot at the bottom:

```
CASE
WHEN overlay_intersects('other layer',filter:=("class" = 1),min_overlap:=($area/2))
THEN 'nice'
WHEN overlay_intersects('other layer',filter:=("class" = 2),min_overlap:=($area/2))
THEN 'mediocre'
ELSE 'not so good'
END
```

[image]

As said, the `filter` allows us to restrict the `true` values to features which have the attribute of interest. `min_overlap` provides an additional, geometry based filter, in this case half of the area of the current feature we're checking for intersection with the other layer.

Comment: Thanks! I used the expression:                                                                                      
CASE
WHEN  overlay_intersects( 'Differenz_742e2289_6bb1_475a_b74b_2485539ba484', filter:=("distance" = 500),min_overlap:=(§area/2)) 
THEN 'Nahversorgung v.a. weniger als 500 m'
WHEN  overlay_intersects( 'Differenz_742e2289_6bb1_475a_b74b_2485539ba484', filter:=("distance" = 1000),min_overlap:=(§area/2)) 
THEN 'Nahversorgung v.a. innerhalb 500-1000 m'
ELSE 'Nahversorgung v.a. weiter als 1000 m'
END

Comment: But received following errors:        
Interpretationsfehler: Invalid QgsExpressionFunction::Parameter name 'min_overlap' for overlay_intersects syntax error, unexpected WHEN, expecting $end Invalid QgsExpressionFunction::Parameter name 'min_overlap' for overlay_intersects syntax error, unexpected ELSE, expecting $end syntax error, unexpected END, expecting $end                                                                             (And I cannot find "min_overlap" in the expression list.)

Comment: It is `$area`, not `§area` @MatThias. Does the `"distance`" field exist, and does it contain the values you're looking for?

Comment: oh, so sorry for the mistake, I put $area now. yes "distance" is a column in "other layer", it has the values '500,000000' and '100,000000'. (is there a way to chose fields and values of another layer in the expression bulider?)  Still get following error: Interpretationsfehler:
Invalid QgsExpressionFunction::Parameter name 'min_overlap' for overlay_intersects
syntax error, unexpected WHEN, expecting $end
Invalid QgsExpressionFunction::Parameter name 'min_overlap' for overlay_intersects
syntax error, unexpected ELSE, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected END, expecting $end

Comment: Which QGIS are you working with?

Comment: 3.22.6-Białowieża

Comment: I am using 3.28.6 currently. Can you upgrade?

Comment: I updated to 3.28, then the expression worked. Many thanks for your support!